# Get table from c++ lua reference index in lua

Tags: c++, lua, reference

first sorry for the weired title :(
I am using lua as a scripting languge for my game and I have a problem:
I am creating lua table instances and storing them in indices "ref_idx " like this:

```
lua_newtable(L);
lua_getglobal(L, "TestTable"); // create instance of table "TestTable"
lua_pcall(L, 0, 1, 0);
ref_idx = luaL_ref(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);
```

and when i want to call a method of one of them I use :

```
lua_rawgeti(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, ref_idx);
lua_getfield(L, -1, "testMethod");
lua_pushvalue(L, -2);
lua_pcall(L, 1, 0, 0));
lua_pop(L, 0);
```

when I am done with the reference :

```
luaL_unref(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, ref_idx);
```

Every thing works fine, the problem is I want to use these reference in lua directly something like :

```
function onUpdate()
   local ref = GetReferenceFromC++() -- returns ref_idx 
   ref:testMethod()
end
```

Any help or a way to do it?
(sorry for my english, I am working on it)

Comment: `debug.getregistry()[ref]:testMethod()`

Answer (score 0):

I used `debug.getregistry()[ref]:testMethod()`
and it works, Thank you @EgorSkriptunoff for your quick response.